# hide and disable two divs by toggle

Tags: jquery

I have two search bar `div`, I need to toggle between those `div` when I select an element. when I toggle either one should be hidden and disabled, toggle is working well but it always shows disabled 2nd `div`. I tried this code but it is not working.

**UPDATED CODE**

```js
$("#tag-search-box").hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);
$("#search_type").change(function() {
    $("#search-box, #tag-search-box").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group row">
       <select name="type" id="search_type" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <option>Books</option>
          <option>Tag</option>
       </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-5 align-items-end" id="search-box">
     <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search books" autocomplete="off">
     <input id="search_submit" value="Search" type="submit">
 </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-5 align-items-end" id="tag-search-box">
     <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search books" autocomplete="off">
     <input id="search_submit" value="Search" type="submit">
 </div>
```

Comment: your code is working ok:https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/aKeGKB or can you explain more ?

Comment: I updated my HTML code. when I toggle the select element the div should be disabled which is hidden, but it is disabling which on the display

Comment: why second input box is `type="submit"` is its a button or textbox?

Comment: its tokenfiled library input field to type multiple tag value, i need two search box with same name

Comment: do you expectiong something like this: https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/aKeGKB?editors=1010

Comment: yes, but the one should be disabled which is hidden, if not when i submit its not taking value from the field coz, both input name is same

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle your inputs `disable` property too. something like the following:

```
$("#tag-search-box").hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);
$("#search_type").change(function() {
    $("#search-box, #tag-search-box").toggle();
    var inpts=$("#search-box, #tag-search-box").find('input');
    $.each(inpts, function(idx, inpt){
          $(inpt).prop('disabled', !$(inpt).prop('disabled'));
    })
});
```

```js
$("#tag-search-box").hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);
$("#search_type").change(function() {
    $("#search-box, #tag-search-box").toggle();
    var inpts=$("#search-box, #tag-search-box").find('input');
    $.each(inpts, function(idx, inpt){
          $(inpt).prop('disabled', !$(inpt).prop('disabled'));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group row">
       <select name="type" id="search_type" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <option>Books</option>
          <option>Tag</option>
       </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-5 align-items-end" id="search-box">
     <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search books" autocomplete="off">
     <input id="search_submit" value="Search" type="submit">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-5 align-items-end" id="tag-search-box">
     <input id="tokenfield" name="search" type="submit" placeholder="Search books by tags" autocomplete="off">
 </div>
```

Comment: its gives in the console error "inpt.prop is not a function"

Comment: my mistake, you should convert `inpt` to `$('inpt') `. I edited my answer.

Comment: still show the input as disabled, the hidden input only should be disabled

Comment: I added code snippet to my answer. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: when I toggle, the div should be disabled which hidden

Comment: do you mean that you are going to disable `div`s instead of hiding theme?

Comment: both the one should be hidden and disabled, check my question snippet, when i toggle its shows the disabled input

Comment: so the code example of my code snippet is doing exact this process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-2 form-group row">
       <select name="type" id="search_type" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <option>Books</option>
          <option>Tag</option>
       </select>
 </div>


 <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-5 align-items-end" id="search-box">
     <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search books" autocomplete="off">
     <input class="search_submit" value="Search" type="submit">
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-5 align-items-end" id="tag-search-box">
     <input id="tokenfield" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search books by tags" autocomplete="off">
   <input class="search_submit" value="Search" type="submit">
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(function() {
  $("#tag-search-box").hide().find('input:not([type="submit"])').prop('disabled', true);
  $("#search_type").change(function() {
    $("#tag-search-box,#search-box").toggle();
    $(".align-items-end:hidden").find('input:not([type="submit"])').prop('disabled', true);
    $(".align-items-end:visible").find('input:not([type="submit"])').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/aKeGKB?editors=1010)

Comment: its disabled and hide it, but press enter not working

Comment: You can't keep two submit buttons in same form, even it hidden. pressing enter always trigger the first submit button

Comment: what if we disabled and hide?

Comment: or you could not disable the submit button, check the updated anser and codepen